# Is "dzeru" : "ceru" a minimal pair in Latvian?

Tags: phonology, minimal-pairs

I'm finding it a bit hard to determine the prosody of these words. I'm basically asking if "dzeru" and "ceru" are prosodically identical.

If "dzeru" : "ceru" isn't a minimal pair which demonstrates the phonemic status of /dz/ and /ts/, is there another Latvian pair which does?